# Find all ideals $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ such that the corresponding factor ring is a UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals, unique-factorization-domains

I'm working on the following problem in Ring Theory:

$\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/\left<y+1\right>$ is a UFD.

> This made me wonder if it is possible to classify all ideals $I$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ such that $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/I$ is a UFD?

Comment: If $R$ is a UFD, $I\subset R$ an ideal there are some necessary conditions for $R/I$ to be a UFD. One simple one is $I$ should be a radical ideal since $R/I=\text{UFD}\to \text{integral domain}\to \text{reduced}$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an open problem. For example, one of the most famous problems in algebraic number theory is to identify the following set: $$\{ n \in \Bbb{N} : \Bbb{Z}[x] / \langle x^2- n \rangle \mbox{ is a UFD } \}$$
it is not even known whether this set is finite or infinite.

This means that your question is already very hard for the ring $\Bbb{Z}[x]$: much harder for $\Bbb{Z}[x,y]$.

Comment: Can we say anything at all about it?